# How to load an element dynamically after page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have a problem to get the DOM element which is loaded dynamically with a database value, and it was not available during page load. Because it will take some fraction of seconds delay during page load. So JQuery does not recognize the element during page load.

How do I gain access to the element after it has loaded?

Comment: As @rahul implied, you're more likely to get a good answer if you can be very specific about what you've tried so far, including any salient code, and what specific results (e.g. error messages) you are seeing.

Answer (score 4):

use below snippet, and write your code inside this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Logic goes here
}
```

This will run after load event

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about elements being initially loaded into the DOM, wrap your code in the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Code here
}
```

This ensured that your javascript code isn't executed until the DOM is fully loaded.

If you are loading the element dynamically using one of the jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) calls, you can supply several callbacks to know when that is complete.

Some dynamically loaded elements may need a [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler when binding DOM events to them. For example:

```
$(".myElem").live("click", function(){
//This event binds to elements loaded dynamically, too
}
```